# How to increase transaction per second limit in microsoft face api?

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-services, face, face-api

i have standard(s0) account on microsoft azure platform, i am trying to make an application to recognize faces from the images. this application will be used by many people simultaneously, currently we have limitation of 10 transaction per second in standard account that means if 10 concurrent user will try to make request at same time, the application will fail. is there any method to solve this problem.

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/cognitive-services/

Comment: Ask Microsoft support...

Comment: To increase the TPS limit for the Face API, Please raise a support ticket.

Answer (score 0):

As per pricing, maximum you can have is 10 transaction per second. According to my knowledge there is no way to handle this as of now. You might need to ask for support from Microsoft inorder to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

For this request ,this is Microsoft Cognitive support team's reply : you can follow [this guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-supportability/how-to-create-azure-support-request) to raise a support ticket , and Azure support team will increase TPS(Transaction Per Second) limit for you based on your past TPS call and then decide on the promotion.